# Unlocking a vote flaw

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bug, edits, voting

On Stack Overflow when you vote (up/down) after 15 minutes or so your vote gets locked in, and it's only through an edit that you would be able to undo your vote.

Just now I downvoted a a question and, after the OP elaborated, I felt my downvote was not fair and I wanted to undo it, so I forced a silly edit on the question and was able to undo the vote.

Is this OK? I feel it's too cheap or not productive; I feel that a user who has voted on a post revision should not be counted, it should be only the post owner or anyone who has not voted on the post.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If it required the OP elaborating on the question before you felt it didn't need a downvote, then that information that changed your mind is what should have been edited into the post before your downvote was removed. That's a perfect example of exactly how the system is supposed to work - if the question didn't make sense to you when you read it, then a downvote is perfectly appropriate until the asker **edits** to make their question clear. There's no reason to change this system.

Comment: I made a mistake in evaluating https://stackoverflow.com/a/54333239/177498 so it was my fault. Why lock-in at all? Can't people change their minds?